# Next js route redirecting to another language getting Invalide attempt hard to navigage

Tags: next.js, routes, locale

in nextjs route.push switching to another language URL getting the following error

[image: I am in the current URL of my website http://localhost:3000/entreposage-mobile/residentiel/ on this page switching to the other language the URL is getting updating to http://localhost:3000/fr/entreposage-mobile/residentiel/ but getting the below issue-->]

Comment: If the origin of the error is not obvious (it looks like you're redirecting to the same url you were already on), we can't help without a snippet of your code.

Answer (score 0):

got the solution in next.config.js rewrites --> destination and source should not end the URL with '/'